# Moving MySQL trigger to DB2; issue with keyword NEW

Tags: mysql, triggers, db2

I have this trigger working in MySQL:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Recharge_trigger
AFTER INSERT ON Recharges
FOR EACH ROW
  UPDATE Balances
  SET Balance = Balance + NEW.Amount
  Where Uid = NEW.Uid AND Stid = NEW.Stid;
```

It automatically updates the `balance` column in the `Balances` table whenever I insert a row in the `Recharges` table.

However when I tried to run it in DB2, it's giving this error:

> Server Error: Error for batch element #1: "NEW.AMOUNT" is not valid in the context where it is used.. SQLCODE=-206, SQLSTATE=42703, DRIVER=3.66.46

I think it's the keyword `NEW` that's messing it up. Is there any way I can write this in DB2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have access to any DB2 database so I couldn't test it but looking at the documentation I think you need to include a `REFERENCING` clause. Try this instead:

```
 CREATE TRIGGER Recharge_trigger
 AFTER INSERT ON Recharges
 REFERENCING NEW AS N
 FOR EACH ROW MODE DB2SQL
 BEGIN ATOMIC
  UPDATE Balances SET Balance = Balance + N.Amount Where Uid = N.Uid AND Stid = N.Stid;
 END
```